# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error while implementing Fractal plant in processing JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, l-systems

I am trying to implement a fractal plant (up-till level - 6) in processing javascript. I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error even though the base conditions are being met.

Here is the code:
First function custom draw line draws line on basis of length, angle and point of origin.
Increment function increases the angle by 25 degree.
Decrement function decreases angle by 25 degree.

```
var customDrawLine = function(x, y, length, angle)
{
    var f={x2:'', y2:''};
    f.x2 = x+(sqrt(sq(length)/(1+sq(tan (angle)))));
    f.y2 = y + ((f.x2-x) * tan (angle));
    line(x, y, f.x2, f.y2);
    return f;
};
var incrementAngle = function(angle)
{
    return (angle+25);
};
var decrementAngle = function(angle)
{
    return (angle-25);
};

var fProductionRule = function(x, y, z, degrees, flag)
{
    var l = {x1:'', y1:''};
    if(flag === 1)
    {
        for (var a=0; a<2;a++)
        {
           l = customDrawLine(l.x1, l.y1, z, degrees);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        l = customDrawLine(l.x1, l.y1, z, degrees);
    }
    return l;
};
var xProductionRule = function(x, y, degrees, nLevel, flag)
{
    var k = {x1:'', y1:''};
    var m;
    k.x1 = x;
    k.y1 = y;
    m = degrees;
    for(var z=0; z<7; z++)
    {
        var f = fProductionRule(k.x1, k.y1, (10-z), m, flag);
        m = incrementAngle(m);
        flag = 1;
        {
            {
                xProductionRule(f.x2,f.y2, m, z);
            }
            m = decrementAngle(m);
            xProductionRule(f.x2,f.y2, m, z);
        }
        m = decrementAngle(m);
        f = fProductionRule(k.x1, k.y1, (10-z), m, flag);
        {
            m = decrementAngle(m);
            f = fProductionRule(k.x1, k.y1, (10-z), m, flag);
            xProductionRule(f.x2,f.y2, m, z);
        }
        m = incrementAngle(m);
        xProductionRule(f.x2,f.y2, m, z);
       }
   };
var drawShape = function(x, y, degrees) 
{
   xProductionRule(x, y, degrees, 0, 0);
};
drawShape(10, 380, 25);
```

Comment: I am using wikipedia page [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) for making fractal plant

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Thanks, much better to read now! Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks for warm welcome :-)

Comment: Please simplify the code by also using `f.x2=x+length*Math.cos(angle); f.y2=y+length*Math.sin(angle);`. Also take care that angle arguments are interpreted as in radians measure. If you give degrees, you have to first convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yor code contains an inifinite recursion, as `xProductionRule` calls itself unconditionally.

To draw fractals, you must either constrain the depth of the recursion, or prevent the rendering of parts under a specific size (like 1 pixel).

I see that `xProductionRule` has 5 arguments, one of them is called `nLevel`, but that argument is not used anywhere, in fact you call the function with only 4 parameters. I think you were to use that argument to constrain the depth of the recursion. Add some check (`nLevel < 7`) to the function, and make every recursive calls to include `nLevel+1` as parameter.

In my opinion, based on the wikipedia article you mentioned, the skeleton of your code should be structured something like this:

```
function drawA(depth, ... /* placement information */) {
    // here, draw the current branch
    // and then continue with it's children
    if (depth > 0) {
        drawA(depth - 1, ... /* derived placement information  */)
        drawB(depth - 1, ... /* another derived placement information  */)
    }
}

function drawB(depth, ... /* placement information */) {
    // here, draw the current branch
    // and then continue with it's children
    if (depth > 0) {
        drawA(depth - 1, ... /* derived placement information  */)
    }
}

drawA(7, ... /* placement of the root branch */)
```

I don't see a place where you would need a 7-loop.

Comment: Thanks... I replaced nLevel Variable with z from the loop. Also changed loop to (for(; z<7;)) <br/>Still same issue

Comment: To be honest i don't really understand why do you even have a loop. On the link you referenced they draw a plant by having one or two child for each node. By using a 7-times loop you basically make 7 child of a node.

Comment: I am using it to draw plant till n=6. Will it not work this way?

Comment: I think this is not the way to do it. You don't need any loops, but you need proper recursion. I added some code to my answer to give you some idea.